# Read the image content and insert into a data frame

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have an SSIS Package in production, which is using a excel connection manager. This package is continuously failing  in the production
I tried to debug the package using Visual Studio 2015 and whenever i update the excel connection manager entire application gets closed

Can any one help me on this

Thanks!
Balaji

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: @NickS1 please review [Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415047/208273) - your edit introduces errors not present in the original code (at the very least, there is no variable called `ing`; I didn't check the whole thing).  Please also see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/165261)

Comment: Hello Ryan, I’ve read the questions you posted in your comment, as you recommended me to do. Should the post be rolled back before my edit, or should I fix my typo? (Of course I’ll no longer edit images and keep the mentioned expressions, from now on)

Comment: @Balaji Well done replacing the image of your code with text. But your edit also eliminated the image of your output. You should provide the output again, but as text.